# Adding an image in React native

Tags: image, react-native

I got this code, and im supposed to add 3 different images to each row.

```
class SubRatingRowGroup extends Component {
    onRatingPressed(elementName, rating) {
        const cat = _.find(this.props.categories_tree.categories, {
            name: elementName
        });
    cat.rating = rating;
    this.props.setSubRatings(cat, rating);
}
handleClick = () => {
    this.props.setCategories( this.props.categories_tree.categories);
  this.props.openSubCategory(this.props.categories_tree, this.props.editable)
}
render() {
    if (this.props.categories_tree && this.props.categories_tree.categories) {
    let subRatingRows = [];
    subRatingRows = this.props.categories_tree.categories.map((category, key) => (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}} key={key}>
        <View style={styles.ratingButtonRow}>
          <View style={styles.buttonNameText} >
            <Button title={category.name} onPress={this.handleClick}  />
                    </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    ));
    return (
        <View >
        {subRatingRows }
            </View>);
        }

    return renderLoadingSpinner();
    }
}
```

This will end with me rendering 3 rows with :
Enviromental
Social
Cultural

and i need 3 different backgrounds on these rows, i'm kinda new so i'm not sure what to do here. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't see where you add your background images. But I'm sure you can use `key` to identify which `background` shows.

Comment: i havent added them here, could you give me an example of how it could look? thanks for fast reply

Comment: You already used it `style={key === 0 ? {background: firstone} : key === 1 ? {background: secondone} : {background: thirdone}}`

Comment: if i got the image on my computer, would it not look like this? getting errors.
 <View
            style={{ flex: 1}}
            key={key}
            style={
               key === 0 ? {background: 
                source={require("../../assets/images/enviromental.png") }/>}
                
             }

Comment: You can't have 2 `style` in one `View`